# textform not taking & symbol in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

Currently I am working on Inventory Project using CodeIgniter. In vendorlist form, I have the following text fields:
Name
Address
Contact Person
and Phone.

This is working correctly for all other texts except & (ampersand) symbol. When I insert & symbol and other text after it, then it does not work at all.

In vendorlist.php file, I am using the following code:

```
<form onsubmit="return false" id="frmvendor">
            <dl>
                <dt><label><?php echo $this->lang->line('name');?></label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="vendorname" id="vendorname" value="" class="validate[required] text-input" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt><label><?php echo $this->lang->line('address');?></label></dt>
                <dd><textarea name="address" id="address" cols="22" class="validate[required] text-input"></textarea></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt><label><?php echo $this->lang->line('phone');?></label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" size="60" class="validate[required] text-input" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt><label><?php echo $this->lang->line('contactperson')?></label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="contactperson" id="contactperson" value="" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt><label><?php echo $this->lang->line('active');?></label></dt>
                <dd>
                <?php echo $this->lang->line('yes');?><input type="radio" name="vendor_locked" checked="checked" value="0" id="vendor_locked" />
                <?php echo $this->lang->line('no');?><input type="radio" name="vendor_locked" value="1" id="vendor_unlocked" />
                </dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt></dt>
                <dd><input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" /><input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="resetForm('frmvendor')" /></dd>
            </dl>

            <input type="hidden" id="vendorid" name="vendor" value="" />
        </form>
```

How can it work for & symbol? Help me guys.

Comment: what does "it does not work at all." Mean? have you received any error ?
if yes then what type of error ?

Comment: Why do you have a new list for each term/description pair?!

Comment: Insert a `&` … where? In the UI? In the HTML?

Comment: It does not shows error. But when I insert & symbol, it does not work for the rest of the texts after &. It does not saves & and rest of the text to the mysql database.

Comment: A `<label>` is for a single form control. Each radio button should have its own label. Use a `<fieldset>` with a `<legend>` for the overall title.

Comment: Your `<input>` elements are not inside your `<label>` elements and your labels have no `for` attribute. You've failed to associate the labels for the inputs, which makes them worthless.

Comment: You shouldn't get the behaviour you describe … `onsubmit="return false"` should prevent any data being submitted so nothing should ever be added to the database, irrespective of there being an `&` or not.

Comment: @Quentin: I Can't post Image because of reputation is less than 10. But, I have a new list for each term because left column is small and I have to adjust this form in the left column.

Comment: @Quentin It is working all other texts and symbols except & symbol. It works well for !, @, #, $, %, ^ etc.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of my own question. The problem was & symbol was considered as variable. So, I created one function on controller and one function on view file.

In Controller file,
I created the following function and used str_replace as:

```
function savevendor()
{
        //print_r ($_POST);
        //die();

    $this->redir->set_last_index();
    $vendor_id  =   $this->input->post('id');

    $refinevendor = str_replace("#_#","&",$this->input->post('vendor'));
    $refineaddress = str_replace("#_#","&",$this->input->post('address'));
    $refinecontactperson= str_replace("#_#","&",$this->input->post('contactperson'));

    $vendordata =   array(
                          'vendor'          =>$refinevendor,
                          'address'         =>$refineaddress,
                          'contact_person'  =>$refinecontactperson,
                          'user_id'         =>$this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                          'phone'           =>$this->input->post('phone'),
                          'upd_date'        =>date('Y-m-d'),
                          'locked'          =>$this->input->post('locked')
                          );


    if((int)$vendor_id==0){
        $arr= array_merge($vendordata,array("ent_date"=>date("Y-m-d")));
        $this->mdl_vendor->save($arr);
        echo $this->lang->line('vendor_has_been_created');
    }else{
        $this->mdl_vendor->save($vendordata,$vendor_id);
        echo $this->lang->line('this_vendor_has_been_saved');
    }
}
```

And in the view file, I created the following function and used .replace as:

function savevendor(){

```
showloading();

var id = $('#vendorid').val();
var vendor = $('#vendorname').val();
var refinevendor = vendor.replace("&","\#_#");

var address = $('#address').val();
var refineaddress = address.replace("&","\#_#");

var phone = $('#phone').val();
var contactperson = $('#contactperson').val();
var refinecontactperson = contactperson.replace("&","\#_#");

var locked  =   $('input:radio[name=vendor_locked]:checked').val();
var params = 'id='+id+'&vendor='+refinevendor+'&address='+refineaddress+'&phone='+phone+'&contactperson='+refinecontactperson+'&locked='+locked+'&unq='+ajaxunq;


$.ajax({
       type     :   'POST',
       url      :   'purchase/savevendor',
       data     :   params,
       success  :   function(data){
                   showVendorTable();
                   resetForm('frmvendor');
                   hideloading(data);
               }
       }) //end of ajax
```

}

and it worked. The thing I actually did was first I replaced the & symbol with `#_#` symbol and then finally I replaced back the symbol `#_#` with &.